# Custom Gradle plugin jar - adding transient dependencies to classpath

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I have created a custom gradle plugin that has transient dependencies. The plugin is working fine and I am outputting the archives to a local maven repo, which again is all working fine. The output directory contains both the pom and jar files.

I want to be able to distribute the plugin between the projects without dependency on the local repo, and without setting up a remote private repo. The obvious choice here is to distibute the jar file between projects, however this requires me to then manually add the transient dependencies of the plugin to a project's classpath.

My questions is how can I distribute a gradle plugin as a jar and have it include transient dependencies without having to manually add those dependencies to a new projects classpath?

Without adding to the classpath I am seeing the following error:

```
Error:(4, 0) Unable to load class 'x'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include: Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.).
The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem. 
Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project. In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

Comment: Is your generated pom included in generated jar ?

Comment: No currently it's in the local maven repo but not included in the jar. Do you know how I include it with the jar?